# Declared and synthesized NSArray works in all methods but one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of NSMutableDictionaries which has been sorted.

This array has been declared and synthesized so that its reachable anywhere in the code. However, its not.

When I try to read it out in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I get 0x5852400 does not appear to point to a valid object in debugger by using the po command, and  I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using NSLog.

Code:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(NSArray*)result
{
    int counter;
    friendsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *d in [result objectForKey:@"data"])
    {   
        [friendsArray addObject:d];
        counter++;
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;

    newfriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    newfriendsArray = [friendsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSLog(@"The new array which works and has been sorted: %@", newfriendsArray);

    [[self tableView] reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    NSLog(@"Array still working here: %@", newfriendsArray);

    return [newfriendsArray count];
}
```

Doing the same NSlog like the ones above in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will cause the simulator to crash.

Comment: can i have some more clearity

Comment: can you please add the complete error log?

Comment: @Anila The question has been updated. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @ganeshmanoj I have tried to explain it better now. See the updated question.

Comment: add your code for more detail?

Comment: add NSLog statement code

Comment: Off topic: I'd suggest switching to ARC and avoid all memory management problems all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a memory management error. In this line:

```
newfriendsArray = [friendsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns an autoreleased object that you need to retain if you want to use it for longer than the current method. The line above:

```
newfriendsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

has no effect other than introduce a memory leak to your code. It seems you have not quite understood when you need to create new objects and when other methods do this for you. In addition, you should really use properties to set your ivars (`self.newFriendsArray = ...;`) to avoid these simple memory management errors.

Comment: Yeah, memory management is really important and I havent had time to learn everything yet since Im quite new at this. Thanks mate!